# nested resources and parameters to form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently reading Beginning Rails 3.  The tutorial creates a blog.  There Users can post Articles as well as Comments to the Articles.  An Article has_many Comments and a Comment belongs_to an Article.  Inside routes.rb we have:

```
 resources :articles do
    resources :comments
 end
```

Now in the 'comments/new.html.erb' file the first line looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.new]) do |f| %>
```

Can someone explain to me why two parameters are needed in the array? What is the second parameter's relationship with a form and especially why is a new instance of a comment being created?

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for nested routes. You're creating a new comments object to hold the input from the user. See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) for the full explanation.